# mySQL pull one ID based on multiple groups

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table as follows:

```
+-----------+--+---------+
| productID |  | GroupID |    
+-----------+--+---------+
|      3428 |  |3        |
|      3428 |  |6        |
|      3428 |  |15       |
|      3428 |  |16       |
|      3428 |  |17       |
|      3428 |  |18       |
|      3428 |  |39       |
|      3428 |  |44       |
|      3428 |  |46       |
|      3428 |  |48       |
|      3428 |  |50       |
+-----------+--+---------+
```

I want a query to pull all products that are in:

(GroupID 3 or 6 or 15) AND (GroupID 16 or 17 or 18)

In this case it will bring back one productID

Comment: Fix the sample data with different `productID's`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
   distinct(productID)
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
    GroupID in (3,6,15)
    or 
    GroupID in (16,17,18)
```

Answer (score 0):

> You should use your `productID` unique.

Because ProductGroup `Has Many` Products, And Products `Belongs To` ProductGroup

Then, You can  try like as -

```
SELECT
  productID
FROM
 YourTableName
WHERE
  (GroupID=3 OR GroupID=6 OR GroupID=15)
    AND
  (GroupID=16 OR GroupID=17 OR GroupID=18)
```